# Macbook Chimes Multiple Times Before Booting, After SSD Upgrade

Tags: macos-mojave, macbook-air, samsung-ssd

I've recently upgraded the ssd in my Mid 2013 MacBook Air, to a Samsung 970 EVO M.2 NVMe. Ever since the upgrade, when I start the computer, it makes the "bong" noise multiple times before the apple logo is displayed on the screen and the booting begins. Sometimes it makes the noise only twice, sometimes it's three times. I tried resetting NVRAM/PRAM after the install, but didn't seem to help.

Comment: When you say "upgraded" the SSD, I assume you mean you removed the old SSD and put in this new one? Did you clone the old SSD to the new one?

Comment: No. I prolly should've though. I ended up making a USB installer and installing 10.14.6. From there, I restored from a TimeMachine backup.

Comment: So you were able to install Mac OS to the new drive, it just won't boot now?

Comment: Yeah, install was successful. It actually does boot every time, but before that, it chimes multiple times. I guess the chime is supposed to indicate a successful POST, but right after the first chime it goes through the process at least one more time before the apple logo and progress bar appears.

Comment: Reset the SMC after any hardware upgrade. https://support.apple.com/HT201295

Comment: Yes, Tetsujin! This seems to have worked!